# Hidden Window Swift

Tags: macos, swift, lsuielement

Is there a way to make an application hidden from the user for an OS X application ( eg not being on the dock when it's open and only operating in the background). I know there is a way to make things like hidden Python windows but can I do it in swift?

Comment: Which platform? Mac OS or iOS? I'm guessing Mac from your use of the word "Dock"

Comment: Made edit to the question, OS X is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `LSUIElement` key to the Info.plist and set its value to 1.

Comment: Remove its icon from the dock and the "tab" app switcher.

Comment: How could they then terminate the app?

Comment: You would need something like a MenuBar item. [Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/98178/os-x-tutorial-menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps) a good tutorial for that. (Put the "Quit" action there)

Comment: If there was no menu bar item, would they not be able to terminate the application?

Comment: They could from Activity Monitor, but that's kind of complicated for a normal user.

Comment: Another way to interact with such a faceless bg app is to provide a System Preferences control panel.